# Are Case statements the answer

Tags: sql, case

I have multiple rows of data for each call that I'm trying to track. The data looks like this

```
Call_ID | site | Agent_key | starttime | exit_reason
----------------------------------------------------
1234     |   7   |           |     1     | transfer
1234     |   3   |  1010101  |     15    | transfer
1234     |   7   |  2121212  |     302   | transfer
1234     |   5   |  3232323  |     680   | transfer
```

I want to create a column called say "first_site". The parameters are site when starttime is min(starttime) and Agent_key is not null. (if Agent_key is null it means the call is still in a call center system so I don't care what site is represented there.

the result would look like

```
Call_ID | site | Agent_key | starttime | exit_reason | first_site |
-------------------------------------------------------------------
1234     |   7   |           |     1     | transfer    |      3     |
1234     |   3   |  1010101  |     15    | transfer    |      3     |
1234     |   7   |  2121212  |     302   | transfer    |      3     |
1234     |   5   |  3232323  |     680   | transfer    |      3     |
```

Any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: Are you using SQL Server, and therefore, could use ROW_NUMBER and PARTITION OVER?

Comment: The query is pulling data from a SQL server but into a tool called Qlikview the query is written in Qlikview

Answer (score 2):

Hope this will help

```
Select t.*, x.first_site
From YourTable t
Inner Join

(Select Call_Id,Min(site) As first_site
From YourTable
Where agent_key is not null -- Where Len(agent_key) > 0
Group By Call_Id)X

On t.Call_Id = x.Call_Id
```

Comment: This was where I started but it doesn't ignore the rows where the agent_key is Null.

Comment: I'm going to comment on this since Niladri did most of the heavy lifting on this one.  I changed the subquery in the join and it should do what you want: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/33dcb/1

Comment: **This answer returns "first_site" as a TIME. The question is after a "site ID".**

Comment: Strike that it won;t work with more than one call_ID gives the site with the lowest of all calls

Comment: @Parker the query you wrote in the sqlfiddle link is the closest we have gotten. It returns the correct value for the example but if we add another call with a different set of values it only returns the lowest of all calls.

Comment: @Parker - see this edit which reveals a fault in your query http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/931e6/1/0 because the min(time) is not correlated.

Comment: @Niladri You're missing the point. It's the site related to the first time, not the `min(site)` that's required.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a simple SCALAR SUBQUERY to achieve this.

```
select outr.*, (select TOP 1 site
                 from tbl
                where call_id=outr.call_id
                  and agent_key is not null
             order by starttime asc) first_site
  from tbl outr;
```

If you need to make up a site, e.g. "IVR" when there isn't any, then use `ISNULL()`

```
select outr.*, ISNULL((select TOP 1 site
                 from tbl
                where call_id=outr.call_id
                  and agent_key is not null
             order by starttime asc), 'IVR') first_site
  from tbl outr;
```

Comment: Richard, this is also a great way to do it. I have a feeling the requestors from on high will ask me next what if it wasn't handle by an agent. Is there any way to say if agent_key is null then first site is "IVR" or something along those lines?

Answer (score 1):

My query execute without additional table join.;)

```
SELECT Call_ID, site, Agent_key, starttime, exit_reason,
       CASE WHEN MIN(CASE WHEN Agent_key IS NOT NULL THEN starttime END) OVER () = starttime 
            THEN site 
            ELSE CASE WHEN MIN(CASE WHEN Agent_key IS NOT NULL THEN starttime END) OVER () != starttime
                      THEN MIN(CASE WHEN Agent_key IS NOT NULL THEN site END) OVER () END
       END AS first_site
FROM dbo.your_table
```

Demo on [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7705f/1/0)